# Different values each time I run the code even with random_state

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Each time I run this code, I get a different value for the print statement. I'm confused why it's doing that because I specifically included the random_state parameter for the train/test split. (On a side note, I hope I'm supposed to encode the data; it was giving "ValueError: could not convert string to float" otherwise).

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data',
                 names=['buying', 'maint', 'doors', 'persons',
                        'lug_boot', 'safety', 'acceptability'])

# turns variables into numbers (algorithms won't let you do it otherwise)
df = df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
print(df)

X = df.reindex(columns=['buying', 'maint', 'doors', 'persons',
                        'lug_boot', 'safety'])
y = df['acceptability']


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

print(X_train)

# decision trees classification
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_true = y_test
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print(math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)))
```

Comment: You need to set `random_state=0` or some other value for [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecisionTreeClassifier` also takes a `random_state` param: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

All you did was ensure that the train/test splits are repeatable but the classifier also needs to ensure it's own seed is the same on each run

**Update**

Thanks to @Chester VonWinchester for pointing out: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8443 due to sklearn's implementation choice it can be non-deterministic with `max_features= None` even though it should mean that all features are considered.

There is further information and discussion in the link above.

Comment: I just want to point out that the decision tree should be a deterministic algorithm when `max_features=None`, but there are some implementation choices that make this not necessarily the case. [This was recently discussed.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8443)

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester yes that's a valid point each model has different training algorithms which can make the results differ slightly

Comment: For sklearn's implementation, I believe it follows from the fact that at each node, all the features are considered (when `max_features=None`), but in a random order each time (due to an implementation choice). Tie events affect the way the tree is grown is subtle ways. There's more detail in my previous link.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester thanks, I've updated the answer to include the link

Comment: Your update is slightly incorrect. It *is* deterministic when `random_state` is supplied. Sorry, let me try to be more clear: I was originally pointing out that with `max_features=None`, the decision tree algorithm is **expected to be** deterministic (according to the usual descriptions from literature), but **due to implementation choices**, it is not (unless `random_state` is supplied).

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester Ah right, I thought your comment was referring to `max_features` exclusively, I'll edit the question, thanks again